# Redis Sentinel Architecture for two node Redis Replication

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

I have two Redis instances, master and a slave, for which I need a High Availability architecture. I am using Sentinel for handling the failover scenario. But when I am using two instances of Sentinel on two individual machines with quorum value 1, and if the Master Redis node with it's Sentinel goes down the other Sentinel unable to promote the Slave node to Master.
Can anyone please suggest the best approach of Sentinel for 2 nodes Redis server?

Comment: If we can have 2 Masters on both the sides ? https://redis-doc-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/sentinel/ See Example 1.